# to_date function strange behaviour for specific year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Different behaviour ,when the date contains year `2000`

```
 select to_date(add_months(sysdate,-50),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual    --error

 ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

  -- 04/08/2000 12:59:15  contains year 2000

 select to_date(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual   --this work,but diff output
```

Comment: What is you default date format? `select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'; `

Comment: @Ramblin'Man:Will let you know tomorrow ,when i reach office

Comment: @Ramblin'Man:My format is `DD/MON/RR`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `TO_CHAR` instead of `TO_DATE`.

The first parameter of [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function is a STRING parameter so here your data is converted to STRING representation and then converted to date format BUT in the DIFFERENT format:

```
to_char(add_months(sysdate,-50),'dd/mm/YYYY')
```

Comment: To expand on this, using the `add_months` function results in a date datatype being returned. You are trying to use `to_date` on a date. This will cause problems as the date will be implicitly converted to string using the session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` before it gets converted back into a date.

Comment: @valex:My question is why it fails for year 2000 and not for other years

Comment: @GauravSoni I'm surprised that it works at all for some dates. In this case error depends on system date format. And it can work on one server and doesn't work on another. If you need `DATETIME` then you should use `add_months(sysdate,-50)` without `TO_DATE` at all if you need VARCHAR use code from my answer. Using `TO_DATE` with `DateTime` as an argument is wrong.

Comment: @valex:Thanks ,but i added add_months because ,the parameter in to_date is been passed from table column having date datat type , just cursious to know ,why it dint work for date having 2000 year

Comment: Consider this. I have added a `to_char` to your initial statement to represent the implicit conversion Oracle will make using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. 

`select to_date( to_char( add_months(sysdate,-50), 'DD/MON/RR' ),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;` The `to_date` is expecting a format of `'dd/mm/yyyy'`, but the string you are converting is in the format `'DD/MON/RR'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query  `select to_date(add_months(sysdate,-50),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual` works fine for me

**Result:**

```
TO_DATE(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-50),'DD/MM/YYYY')
---------------------------------------------
04-OCT-09
```

Comment: What is your 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' set to? It is working by chance!